# JAX-RS 2.0 UriBuilder exception

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jax-rs, uribuilder

I've been dealing with this issue for over two days now, I've looked at all the tickets that I could find that are even remotely to this issue. I've tried using different versions of JAX-RS but it always comes down to this issue.

I recently saw the need to implement Async requests in my servlet. before this it was working perfectly using JAX-RS 1.9 But as soon as I add the dependencies required to use `@ManagedAsync` annotation I get the error below

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried looking for dependency issues but I couldn't find any and I will feel very silly if someone points one out right away. but I went through all the packages in my build path, not just maven but also my JRE and Tomcat but to no avail

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>MyRestAPI</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyRestAPI</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20140107</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.json</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                 <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.0</version>
                 <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                         <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                         <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Axis -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                <version>0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>       
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyRestAPI</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>My Rest API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.myrest.servlets.Users</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Rest API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Users class

```
package com.myrest.servlets;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.myrest.handlers.RequestHandler;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Users extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(RequestHandler.class);

        return classes;
    }
}
```

RequestHandler class

```
package com.myrest.handlers;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ManagedAsync;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.myrest.beans.UserBean;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

@Path("user")
public class RequestHandler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestHandler.class);

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void acceptUser(UserBean user, @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) throws UnknownHostException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String payloadStr = gson.toJson(user);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler(user, true, latch);
        userHandler.start();

        try {
            latch.await();

            JsonObject userJson = new JsonParser().parse(userHandler.userJSON).getAsJsonObject();

            asyncResponse.resume(userJsonString);
        }catch( Exception e) {
            asyncResponse.resume("{\"error\": \"There was a problem on server side. Please contact the Administrator (Empty Payload)\","+
                    "\"code\" : 600}");

        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help and if it is a dependency issue..... I'll cry myself to sleep tonight...

Comment: Upvoted, because I don't want you to cry yourself to sleep tonight.  Sorry I don't know the answer.